# ¿Cómo crear un How to play?

Tags: android

Hace unos días terminé un juego de tablero para android, como si fueran unas damas con más tipos de movimientos, pero a las personas que se los mostre les costó aprender los movimientos. Actualmente tiene una actividad para enseñar a jugar. Me gustaría que la primera vez que se juegue aparecieran consejos de cómo jugar al comenzar la partida (como muchos juegos tienen, adjunto foto de ejemplo).[image]

La idea es hacer algo similar a la mano esa con las lineas amarillas, una imagen que se mueva (un dedo) indicando los gestos posibles.

Comment: Puede que te sirve mejor: https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

Comment: Otra libreria mucho mas estilizada a material design y te dejo un tutorial http://blog.grafixartist.com/material-design-onboarding-android-quickstart-tap-target/?utm_content=buffer2fcc0&utm_medium=social&utm_source=plus.google.com&utm_campaign=buffer

Answer (score 2):

eso se llama onboarding, es como una especie de tarjetas de explicación que salen al inicio, es eso lo que quieres, aqui hay un [ejemplo](https://material.uplabs.com/posts/onboarding-familylocator).

Lo que yo haria es hacer una intruccion de ese tipo, que salga siempre cuando es la primera vez que entra a la aplicacion, una pagina, cuando haga lo de la primera pagina pase  la segunda, cuando complete el tutorial, entonces si empiece el juego, y que no salga mas; osea que exista na variable como

```
firstTime === true -- onboardingShow

firstTime === False  -- onboardingHide
```

Pienso yo asi, no se que otra recomendación te darán.

Comment: Onboarding, yo las tengo por welcomescreens o introapp

Comment: @Webserveis pues pienso que tendran parecidos o diferentes propositos